# "VERY SUBJECTIVE" this is now closed

Tags: discussion

i thought this was a physics forum open to all,but it is very elitist and moderated to suit,your way or no way.i may not be able to speak the language of science naming certain "laws and formulas" but i understand most of what i read and find that with all your "schooled learning" you have lost the ability to think outside the box.i came here hopeing for some kind of input but got closed down,i thought "science" was open to everyone but it seems it is a closed circle here.does it hurt to give help to others who have no where else to go or perhaps helpful guidance?once you define something you put it in a box where it then loses its ability to grow.i am sorry to post this but i see this trend of group snobbery is growing into many areas and saddens me,i have time for everyone whoever or whatever they are.i am not closed to anything,without one piece you have an incomplete picture....i've had my say sorry again for polluting this ivory tower.

Comment: Could you at least use punctuation and whitespace properly? Don't know what you're ranting about, but yes I'd say having you around would be pollution.

Comment: Possibly triggered by the closing of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37858/520.

Comment: thank you crazy buddy,wish there where more like you,it is not hard to be polite and give pointers when you can.it is good to meet a open person some become to closed and will never see.may your vision be always clear.

Comment: @CrazyBuddy something makes me suspect you and mark are one and the same. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but please knock it off.

Comment: zephyr you've got to be crazy buddy to think that.

Comment: Hi mark, was it the question that dmckee linked to being closed that annoyed you? Is it your question? I've just looked at it and it was very difficult for me to read, since it contains almost no punctuation. This gives the reader no time for breathing and makes reading very tedious. In addition, it would help if you could break down your posts in paragraphs, if you have a lot of things to say. This goes for the closed question and the meta question here.

Comment: If you are interested in black holes, relativity, cosmology, etc you should probably try to find out a bit more about these things, such that you can better apply the language people use who are working on such topics and relate your ideas to known facts, before trying to ask questions here. Lenny Susskind has give some very nice free video-lectures about relativity and cosmology that everybody who had just a tiny bit of calculus can understand. Things are not that bad here on physics SE ;-). On Meta Stack Overflow you can easily get 30 downvotes in 2 hours, I know what I'm talking about :-D

Comment: @CrazyBuddy I know you're on some crazy crusade here, and I see two users with atrocious grammar and suspiciously similar phrasing and turns of speech supporting each other. So if I see much more like this I probably will be approaching the moderators to see what actual investigation should be done.

Comment: Come on guys, this isn't helping anyone. @zephyr I'll save you some time: there is no concrete evidence to support that accusation. But in the future, if you have a similar suspicion, just bring it to the moderators' attention.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

But more importantly: while this site is open to everyone, in the sense that we don't require any particular academic or other qualifications to join, it is an expert level site. That means that we expect contributors to understand the physics relevant to the question they want to ask. In other words, when you want to contribute you have to do so using the language of science, or something close enough to it that we can understand what you're talking about. (See points 1 and 2, especially, of [this blog post](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/2007/06/19/the-alternative-science-respectability-checklist/) for a more in-depth discussion of what I'm getting at.)

If this is a problem, there are some other physics sites on the web (e.g. [Reddit Physics](http://www.reddit.com/r/Physics) and [Physics Forums](http://www.physicsforums.com)) which *might* have different standards for what they expect of contributors, so it's *possible* that you may get more useful feedback there.

Comment: i do apologize and understand that this was the wrong site for my writing talents.but you do have a very good site with good solid physics which i will continue to visit do not worry i will leave my writing talents at the door.

Comment: Really puzzling how reddit physics can attract stars like this user: http://www.reddit.com/user/TomatoAintAFruit/

Comment: Actually there might be more advanced experts on Reddit Physics than there are here. It does have the advantage of a longer history.

Answer (score 3):

All I can do for you is direct you to the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq). In particular, I recommend to you the parts where [it says that you should not post questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) that are *"[p]itches for your own personal theories or work"*, where it [says that you should stick to](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"*, and of course the part where it talks about [why some questions are closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#close).

The site *is* open to all---and indeed to anonymous use for writing questions and answers--but we reserve the right to police it to maintain a focused and useful environment for other users. We have a community here that has done a lot of work to create a useful resource for getting physics questions answered. We'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Mark, I can understand your frustration, and physics is sometimes very difficult even for trained professionals.  I would agree that sometimes the comments made could be done in softer tones, however, there are reasons why people who love physics get defensive.  First of all, knowledge is perishable, even in this day in age of instantaneous answers, noise can frequently obscure what has been shown as fact within certain structures of logical reasoning.  At some level that is what physics is, a structure of logical reasoning about the world.  I think most physicists actually strive everyday to be able to think of something new to say about the world, however they need to be respectful of all the facts that have been determined before.  My only word of advice is to not be discouraged.  I think if you really want to learn, people will do their best to help, however, there are certain things that people have shown actually work and have studied intensely and will not accept certain answers they know are wrong.  Just keep moving and eventually a lot of this will make sense.